# Can Azure test plans be automated to run all test cases before continuing?

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops, automation, automated-tests

My team manages a WPF application through Azure DevOps.
For each release version, we want to run all of our Azure test plans, which include our user tests.
To do this, we want our release pipeline to reset all tests to "active" and then basically wait until all tests are complete.
This seems like a relatively easy task to me, as (hopefully) many companies will want to review their software in a structured way before releasing it.
However, I can't find an easy way to do this without diving into the Azure Rest API.
Am I missing something or are Azure test plans not designed for this type of use?

I've tried to run `- task: VSTest@2` with the testplan and testsuite parameters but obviosly my agent is a headless server that cannot run user tests.

Comment: I think better to use frameworks  like Selenium or Appium. they allow you to script user interactions and simulate user actions. You can then include these automated tests in your release pipeline using the appropriate test execution task, such as the VSTest@2 task.